# designing a firewall for Java or symbian mobiles...?

Tags: firewall

creating a firewall application for Java enabled mobiles?

Comment: Don't include your email, people will respond to this topic only. And I think a little less exclamation marks/question marks would serve you well.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why?  Since your IP address may change during the time you're using the phone and there is a better than 50% chance that you'll just have an IP address inside a private (class A) domain - this seems unnecessary - unless you're just curious about how to do it (in which case, have fun!)

Answer (score 2):

J2ME applications are user level - they cannot intercept TCP/IP traffic at the kernel level.

You need to implement a kernel module in order to actually implement the firewall.